# How to delete browser malware?

Tags: malware, web-browser, virus, chrome

I've got some malware so now my browser is sending requests to strange sites: 
[image]
Also if I click on any html element in a browser It may redirect me to unwanted pages

I've tried to fix this using malwarebytes and adwcleaner and other basic cleaning methods like reinstalling the browser, cleaning the Task planner in windows, deleting some extensions in browser, cleaning regestry etc.

So the question is how do I fix my browser from this ads with free software or any other methods?

Comment: The screenshot you posted is not evidence of malware.

Comment: Maybe the Problem isn't your browser. Consider that it's your DNS Server which redirects you to different pages you requestet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the kind of malware. If it's *just* a malicious browser extension with no outside-of-the-browser components - which you can test by disabling all browser extensions and seeing if the problem goes away - then it's easy. All you'd need to do is delete (and possibly report) the malicious extension. Of course, the attacker could still have had all your passwords, cookies, and so forth that were used while the malicious extension was installed, so you'd have some other clean-up work to do, but that should be enough to get it off your computer.

However, if it's any other sort of malware - including a Chrome "app" or some kinds of high-privilege extension - then you have to assume that the machine is compromised. As a general rule, it's not safe to assume that you completely removed malware via any means short of re-installing the operating system (and, if it executed with sufficient privileges and was unusually sophisticated, some malware might even embed itself in some of the computer's firmware and survive an OS reinstall).

---

With that said... how sure are you that it's malware? https://xkcd.com/1180/ is only a slight exaggeration. Most of the failed XMLHttpRequests in your screenshot don't actually look malicious at all; they're things like a script from Facebook.com trying to load a video from Facebook's Content Distribution Network domain (fbcdn.net), or Twitch trying to access an analytics server (presumably to track information about how you use the site, which is common). The "if I click on any html element in a browser It may redirect me to unwanted pages" thing is way more concerning, but also extremely vague; there's lots of things you could mean by that, and only some of them are even suggestive of malware.